# Google Places charging stations fields retrieval problem

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm developing an app for calculating the routes of electric cars through the recharge points obtained on the google map(charging stations). I need to get the type of recharge connection via API (CHAdeMO, CCS, Type2 etc).

[Here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/ENEL+Charging+Station/@41.544267,13.4421682,12z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1scharging+station!3m4!1s0x13254cef76cf11ab:0x846f8611f3b3008b!8m2!3d41.544267!4d13.512206?hl=it)'s an example query with fields I need.

Are these fields included in the Google Places API?
I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Charging station" is not a [supported place type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) so you can't filter charging stations by recharge type either through the Places API.

However, there are feature requests for this in Google's Issue Tracker which I recommend starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future notifications:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111378624
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63055661

Hope this helps!